# iMX6Q IPU Foreground/Background Operation

Tags: graphics, imx6

I'm trying to get foreground/background operation working on the iMX6Q processor. DMA channel 23 is used for the background and 27 for the foreground. Channel 23 by itself works fine and I get a good image. But enabling channel 27 (and enabling color keying and global alpha) produces what looks like a timing issue. Can the DP module in the IPU actually combine two full plane images? Anyone know how Gstreamer does it?

The images show the background by itself and then enabling a red (supposed to be opaque) red square.